# How can I save results from my DecisionTreeRegressor to different array when I modify the "max_depth"?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following problem:
I am using DecisionTreeRegressor and need to save the results of my RSME (training and test) as I change the "max_depth".

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=25)
tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train_pred = tree_reg.predict(X_train)
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
tree_train_mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred)
print("RMSE Train: ", np.sqrt(tree_train_mse))
RMSE Train:  2178.5783334392877 # this is the value to save

y_test_pred = tree_reg.predict(X_test)
tree_test_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)
print("RMSE Test: ", np.sqrt(tree_test_mse))
RMSE Test:  25188.114240007588 # this is other value to save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you test the following values as `max_depth`: [5,10,15].

Use a `for` loop and store the results:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

for value in [5,10,15,25]:

    tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = value)
    tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_train_pred = tree_reg.predict(X_train)

    tree_train_mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred)
    print("RMSE Train: ", np.sqrt(tree_train_mse))

    y_test_pred = tree_reg.predict(X_test)
    tree_test_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_pred)
    print("RMSE Test: ", np.sqrt(tree_test_mse))

    with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write("RMSE Train: " + np.sqrt(tree_train_mse))
        f.write("RMSE Test: " + np.sqrt(tree_test_mse))
        f.write("max_depth: " + max_depth)
        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can looking to save the file in a plain `txt` format you can just save it using this

```
with open('RMSE.txt', 'a') as f: # note that "a" is to append each line on top of your file
    f.write("max_depth: " + max_depth)
    f.write("RMSE Train: " + np.sqrt(tree_train_mse))
    f.write("RMSE Test: " + np.sqrt(tree_test_mse))
    f.write('\n')
```

Having everything in your computer memory is generally not good if you are doing long operations that may break the script. What you can do is to save into a plain `txt` file which you can access in the future.